# Go Redis JSONGet to map

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

Been dabbing in Redis with Go 1.19 as the backend lang and have been stuck trying to convert the JSONGet return value (res interface{}) to a map. I'm using "github.com/nitishm/go-rejson/v4" as the Redis JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Let me know what you all think!

```
func RawRedisJSONToMap(redisObj interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    ba := make([]byte, 0, len(redisObj.([]uint8)))
    for _, b := range redisObj.([]uint8) {
        ba = append(ba, b)
    }
    var m map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(ba, &m)
    return m
}
```